# Finding content controls within Word table cells

Tags: vba, ms-word, contentcontrol, word-table

I am basically looping through all the cells within all the tables of a given Word document. I want to be able to identify cells that contain ContentControlls. Is this possible?

At least in terms of text length, cells with only ContentControls appear to be empty (other than the normal two cell end characters)

Comment: What about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.contentcontrols#:~:text=Returns%20a%20ContentControls%20collection%20that%20represents%20the%20content%20controls%20contained%20within%20a%20range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```vb
Dim c As Cell

Set c = ActiveDocument.tables(1).Cell(3,3)
Debug.Print c.Range.ContentControls.Count
```

Comment: Thank you! I have worked a lot with VBA in Excel but this is my first VBA Word project. Your answer also helped on a separate issue.